# Detecting collision between sprites

Tags: java, libgdx, collision

My game has two classes both of them spawn sprites the only difference is that their sprite move in different directions.

```
public void newSprite(float x,float y){
        Sprite sprite= Pools.obtain(Sprite.class);
        sprite.set(Mysprite);
        sprite.setPosition(x,y);
        arrayList.add(sprite);
    }

if(condition==true){
  newSprite(); //calls the method to spawn a new sprite
}
```

however how do I detect if sprites from the other class collided to this one, there are a lot of sprites that is being spawned from both classes. My idea is to create a rectangle for each sprite by using pool as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Arguments**

This method also takes in two sprites

**Assumptions**

This method assumes that both sprites contain the properties `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`.

**Returns**

This method returns a boolean to say whether they collide or not.

```
bool detectCollision(Sprite sprite1, Sprite sprite2) {

    return ((sprite1.x <= sprite2.x && (sprite2.x + sprite2.width) - sprite1-x <= sprite1.width + sprite2.width) ||
            (sprite1.x >= sprite2.x && (sprite1.x + sprite1.width) - sprite2.x <= sprite1.width + sprite2.width)) && // Check for x 
        ((sprite1.y <= sprite2.y && (sprite2.y + sprite2.height) - sprite1.y <= sprite1.height + sprite2.height) || 
            (sprite1.y >= sprite2.y (sprite1.y + sprite1.height) - sprite2.y <= sprite1.height + sprite2.height)); // Check for y

}
```

This method checks the outermost sides of each rectangle and detects if the distance is less than the width or height of the combined two. If both axis check this as true, it's guaranteed that they are touching.

Tell me if it works!

Comment: ok I'll tell you tomorrow, it's 12am here I really need some sleep. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the distance between the two sprites (from their center).  If the distance between them is less than the sum of half their radii, then u have collision.